# PHP snippet Code Security

Tags: php

I am writing this in PHP

```
$edit_window = $database_info->timestamp + 86400;
$current_timestamp = time ();

if ($current_timestamp > $edit_window){
        $database_info->editable = TRUE;
     } 
else {
        $database_info->editable = FALSE;
     }
```

then

```
if ($database_info->editable){
//do some major stuff
}
```

Somehow this code is worrying me. Is it open to vulnerablities? Is there a better approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't look vulnerable. Are you storing any user-provided data in the database (or inserting it into HTML) or relying on cookies or headers that could be spoofed?

Comment: Well the database timestamp itself is created programmatically, but the current code is called by passing parameters in url, something like http://example.com/auth?some_id_parameter=3453656

Comment: Perhaps you want to make sure the parameters are "sanitized"...ie. not an invalid timestamp? (Pretty vague question=P)

Comment: I guess that my concerns are ill-founded. Thanks

Comment: Just validate the `some_id_parameter` to make sure it's what you think it is (an integer) and you'll be fine.